# Does the set of the normal vectors of the points of a smooth closed surface contain every unit vector $u: u\in \mathbb R^3$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I am trying to prove the following: Consider a closed smooth surface  and let the normal vector at a point $x,y,z$ being expressed as $\vec n(x,y,z)$ I am trying to show that for every $\vec w: w\in \mathbb R^3,|\vec w|=1$ there is some $(x,y,z)$ that belongs to the surface such that $\vec n(x,y,z)=\vec w$. I have not met that in any book and is a hypothesis I made that seems to me obvious even though I cannot prove.Is my hypothesis right? If yes how can it be proven?

Comment: This is certainly false as stated. Try $\vec R(u,v) = u\vec i + v\vec j + 0\vec k$. Or try $\vec R(u,v) = u\vec i + v\vec j + (u^2+v^2)\vec k$. In other words, try examples. Your title has something else in it, however, which is not in the body of your question.

Comment: @TedShifrin you are right I forgot to mention in the body that I am referring to closed surfaces.I fixed it

Comment: You cannot write a global parametrization of a closed surface. So you need to revise. You might want to edit to say precisely what *closed* means in this context.

Comment: @TedShifrin What do you mean by global?

Comment: There is no single parametrization that covers all the points of a closed (compact without boundary) surface. Try to do a sphere, for example.

Comment: @TedShifrin Isnt the parametrization $x(u,v)=cos(u), y(u,v)=sin(u)cos(v), z(u,v)=sin(u)sin(v)$ which reffers to a sphere of radius $R=1$ considered global?

Comment: No. It has various problems. First, if you use an open set as the domain, it does not cover the sphere. Second, the derivative of the mapping drops rank at $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: I just want to point out that, if I understand your question correctly, another way of phrasing it is asking if the Gauss map of any closed surface is surjective or not.

Comment: Assuming the surface is compact (i.e. closed and bounded), then for example $z$ has a maximum value somewhere on the surface; and at the point where $x_n$ is maximized, the normal vector must be $k$.  Can you see a way to generalize that argument to get every other unit vector as a normal vector?  (On the other hand, if you don't require boundedness, then the $xy$-plane would be an obvious counterexample.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $u\in \mathbb{R}^3$ s.t $|u|=1$. Consider a plane $P_R=\{ v\in \mathbb{R}^3| 
v\cdot u = R\}$. If $R$ is very large, then there is no intersection between $P_R$ and the given closed surface (i.e. **compact without boundary**). If we make $R$ smaller (we are pulling the plane to the origin), then for some $R$, the plane $P_R$ is tangent to the closed surface. Here at the intersection point, the closed surface has a normal vector $u$. Hence *Gauss map is surjective*.

**Add :** But if we omit the condition of closedness, the plane $P_R$
can not be tangent : Consider revolution surface of the plane curve $$y=\frac{1}{x},\ x>0$$ along $x$-axis. And define $u=(-1,0,0)$. Then an intersection set between two surfaces always divides the revolution surface into two components transversally.