# Trying to prove an observation for closed,smooth-boundary surfaces of three dimensional convex sets.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry

I was thinking of the consequences that follow for a smooth surface $D$ which is the border of a convex, bounded three-dimensional set.Taking into consideration that the set of normal vectors $\vec n(x,y,z)$ of a smooth surface $D$  contains every unit vector $\vec u: \vec u\in \mathbb R^3$ as I was discussing in the question :[Does the set of the normal vectors of the points of a smooth closed surface contain every unit vector $u: u\in \mathbb R^3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4518196/does-the-set-of-the-normal-vectors-of-the-points-of-a-smooth-closed-surface-cont) from my experience with convex sets I have been convinced that there exists a $1-1$ function $f:(x,y,z)\in D\rightarrow \vec n(x,y,z)$ which finally means  that any unit vector $\vec u \in \mathbb R^3$ we can think of will appear exactly once in the set of the normal vectors $S$ which refers to the smooth,closed surface $D$.From what I have seen in a variety of three-dimensional convex sets  this seems to apply, however I have not yet managed to find  any proof of it so I am looking for help. Any help is appreciated

Comment: If $D$ contains an open subset of a plane, then the function will not be injective. There are plenty of convex sets with smooth boundaries that have that property.

Comment: @JackLee You are right. I had not thought of such an example. However can we prove that  a surface that satisfies the above properties (the properties mentioned in my question) is the boundary of a three dimensional convex set?